# If a value is available in one collection then I want to take one data otherwise I want to take another value in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am working on a project where I have data like below. I want to use MongoDB aggregation. Here some objects have the **likes** value and some don't. Now I want to use the value of likes if it is available otherwise I want to take the value of dislikes. If no like or dislike is available I don't want to take this.

```js
const data = [
{  _id :0, name:"jane",  joined : ISODate("2011-03-02"), dislikes: 9},
{  _id :1, name: "joe",  joined : ISODate("2012-07-02")},
{  _id: 2, name: "Ant",  joined: ISODate("2012-07-02"),  likes: 60, dislikes: 02},
{  _id: 2, name: "Ant",  joined: ISODate("2012-07-02"), dislikes: 12},
{  _id: 2, name: "Ant",  joined: ISODate("2012-07-02"), dislikes: 12},
{  _id: 2, name: "Ant",  joined: ISODate("2012-07-02"), }
],
```

Output will be like:

```json
[
{  _id :0, name:"jane",  joined : ISODate("2011-03-02"), dislikes: 9},
{  _id: 2, name: "Ant",  joined: ISODate("2012-07-02"),  likes: 60, dislikes: 02},
{  _id: 2, name: "Ant",  joined: ISODate("2012-07-02"), dislikes: 12},
{  _id: 2, name: "Ant",  joined: ISODate("2012-07-02"), dislikes: 12},
],
```

Is there any way I can do the aggregation? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap the 2 `$exists` criteria in a `$or`.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      likes: {
        $exists: true
      }
    },
    {
      dislikes: {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qQDrBvT4Nzs)