# If a value is available in one collection then I want to take one data and addField otherwise I want to take another value in addField aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am working on a project where I have data like below. I want to use MongoDB aggregation. Here some objects have the likes value and some don't. Now I want to use the value of likes if it is available otherwise I want to take the value of the sum of likes and dislikes. If no like or dislike is available I don't want to take this. I want to add a new field and put the named *reaction* and return the docuemnt with the reaction value.

```
const data = [
{  _id :0, name:"jane",  joined : ISODate("2011-03-02"), dislikes: 9},
{  _id :1, name: "joe",  joined : ISODate("2012-07-02")},
{  _id: 2, name: "Ant",  joined: ISODate("2012-07-02"),  likes: 60, dislikes: 02},
{  _id: 2, name: "Ant",  joined: ISODate("2012-07-02"), dislikes: 12},
{  _id: 2, name: "Ant",  joined: ISODate("2012-07-02"), dislikes: 12},
{  _id: 2, name: "Ant",  joined: ISODate("2012-07-02"), }
],
```

Output will be like:

```
[
{  _id :0, name:"jane",  joined : ISODate("2011-03-02"), dislikes: 9, reactions: 9},
{  _id: 2, name: "Ant",  joined: ISODate("2012-07-02"),  likes: 60, dislikes: 2, reactions: 60},
{  _id: 2, name: "Ant",  joined: ISODate("2012-07-02"), dislikes: 12, reactions: 12},
{  _id: 2, name: "Ant",  joined: ISODate("2012-07-02"), dislikes: 12, reactions: 12},
],
```

I am still learning the aggregation that's why I was wondering is there a way I could do this? Thank you.

I tried something like these but did not work:

```
{
    
      
    $or: [
      {
        "likes" : {
           
        reaction: {
          $add: [
      "$likes",
      "$dislikes",
    ]
        
      
        }
      },
      
      {
        "dislikes" : {
           reaction: {
        "dislikes}
      
        }
      },
      ]
  }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand the question.
Is it :
Case 1 : document has `likes` but no `dislikes` -> addField `reaction` = `likes`
Case 2 : docuement has `dislikes` but no `likes` -> addField `reaction` = `dislikes`
Case 3 : document has both -> addField `reaction` = `likes` + `dislikes`
Case 4 : document has neither -> remove doc from result

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75163802) to your other question, perform `$match` with `$exists` wrapped in `$or` first. Then, sum up the values with `$ifNull` wrapped.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          likes: {
            $exists: true
          }
        },
        {
          dislikes: {
            $exists: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "reactions": {
        $add: [
          {
            "$ifNull": [
              "$likes",
              0
            ]
          },
          {
            "$ifNull": [
              "$dislikes",
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jMdxTnAXmaZ)